# Need to code Status in Excel from Start and End Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that contains Start and End Dates of users. I added an extra column which is parameter. I.e Users of the spreadsheet will have to enter their desired date in the Column. The Conditions to determine the status of users are as follows.

```
IF [Start Date] <= [Parameter A] 
AND  ISNULL([Termination Date])
THEN 'active'
ELSEIF [Start Date] <= [End Date]
AND [End Date] >= [Parameter A]
THEN 'active'
ELSE NULL
END
```

It is important to not that this code above is not in Excel, this is a tableau code with the same logic. 
This is code i came up with in Excel

```
=IF(AND(J2<='Data Calculation'!$E$2,K2=""),"ACTIVE",IF(AND(J2<=K2,K2>='Data Calculation'!$E$2),"ACTIVE",""))
```

Where J2 is the Start Date, 'Data Calculation'!$E$2 is the Date parameter that the user will define, K2 is the Termination Date.

Comment: What is wrong with the formula you came up with?

Comment: When i set the Date Parameter to 1/1/2015, some records with start date of 2016 and End date of 2019 still how up as Active. i think this part of the code is faulty. ````IF(AND(J2<=K2,K2>='Data Calculation'!$E$2),"ACTIVE",""))````

Comment: Then you need to add one more check to make sure the date is not before the start date.

Comment: Where do you recommend i add this ? Can you provide sample code please ?

Comment: `AND(J2<=K2,K2>='Data Calculation'!$E$2,J2<='Data Calculation'!$E$2)`

Comment: Scott, i'm kinda slow. Can you please provide full recommended code ?

Comment: replace the second AND with the one I provided.